# How to transpose words backwards?

Tags: text-editing

Transpose words (`M-t`) always swaps the word with the next.

How can this be performed with the previous word?

Answer (score 5):

Use a prefix argument, as the documentation indicates:

> (transpose-words ARG)
>
> Interchange words around point, leaving point at end of them.
>   With prefix arg ARG, effect is to take word before or around point
>   and drag it forward past ARG other words (backward if ARG negative).
>   If ARG is zero, the words around or after point and around or after mark
>   are interchanged.

<kbd>C-u -1 M-t</kbd> works for your specific case.

Comment: So when calling from a single key shortcut, I would need to use a function to set this argument?

Comment: `M--M-t` is shorter

Comment: If you're calling `(transpose-words)` in your key binding, change it to call `(transpose-words -1)` instead.